# attribute in entity class has a mappedBy value which does exist in its owning entity

Tags: java, jpa, entity, entity-relationship, jpql

What is wrong with `Article.foo` to cause: `Exception Description: The attribute [foos] in entity class [class net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Article] has a mappedBy value of [foos] which does not exist in its owning entity class [class net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Foo].`?

`Foo` does not have a mappedBy value of foos, is that a correct reading?  That is because `Foo` has a mappedBy value as:  `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "articles")`.

How can I fix these entities so that they're many-to-many?

I tried to follow the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html):

```
Example 1:

// In Customer class:

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="CUST_PHONES")
public Set<PhoneNumber> getPhones() { return phones; }

// In PhoneNumber class:

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="phones")
public Set<Customer> getCustomers() { return customers; }
```

why are the annotations for the relationships on methods and not on fields?  This seems to have mucked me up in that I'm not sure what fields should be in which entity for my code.

After trying as above I made some changes as suggested by the IDE and ended up with:

stack:

```
Jul 30, 2012 3:49:47 AM net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver.Main main
SEVERE: null
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18ad9a0
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [USENETPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7154] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The attribute [foos] in entity class [class net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Article] has a mappedBy value of [foos] which does not exist in its owning entity class [class net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Foo]. If the owning entity class is a @MappedSuperclass, this is invalid, and your attribute should reference the correct subclass.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:115)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver.Main.<init>(Main.java:34)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver.Main.main(Main.java:24)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [USENETPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7154] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The attribute [foos] in entity class [class net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Article] has a mappedBy value of [foos] which does not exist in its owning entity class [class net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Foo]. If the owning entity class is a @MappedSuperclass, this is invalid, and your attribute should reference the correct subclass.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1385)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.callPredeploy(JPAInitializer.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:105)
    ... 4 more
```

Articles entity:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Article implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Article.class.getName());
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String subject;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "foos")
    private Set<Foo> foos;

    public Article() {
    }

    public Article(Message message) {
        try {
            subject = message.getSubject();
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Article.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

        public Set<Foo> getFoos() {
        return foos;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Article)) {
            return false;
        }
        Article other = (Article) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return subject;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }
}
```

Foo entity:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Foo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "articles")
    private Set<Article> articles;

    public Foo() {
    }

        public Set<Article> getArticles() {
        return articles;
    }

        public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Foo)) {
            return false;
        }
        Foo other = (Foo) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Foos[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

`mappedBy = "foos"` means: go see the other side of this bidirectional association to see how it's mapped. The other side is the attribute `foos` in the target entity.

So, since you have a field

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "foos")
private Set<Foo> foos;
```

your JPA engine looks for an attribute named `foos` (since mappedBy = "foos") in the class `Foo` (since it's a `Set<Foo>`). It doesn't find any such attribute, and thus complains.

One and only one side (the inverse side) of a bidirectional association must have the `mappedBy` attribute. The side without the `mappedBy` attribute is the owner side. So, if you want Article to be the owner of the association, you must have:

```
public class Article {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(...)
    private Set<Foo> foos;
}


public class Foo {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "foos")
    private Set<Article> articles;
}
```

If you want Foo to be the owner of the association, you must have

```
public class Article {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "articles")
    private Set<Foo> foos;
}


public class Foo {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(...)
    private Set<Article> articles;
}
```